# Rounded edges Gauge with Highcharts.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to create a custom gauge, the pane shape should be rounded as the attached pic, wondering if anyone has an idea of how to implement this layout using the library

This is the http://jsfiddle.net/ao9fv2yh/ I am using as a starting point.

```
$(function () {

var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// The speed gauge
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));

// The RPM gauge
$('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'RPM'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RPM',
        data: [1],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
        }
    }]

}));

// Bring life to the dials
setInterval(function () {
    // Speed
    var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
        point,
        newVal,
        inc;

    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }

    // RPM
    chart = $('#container-rpm').highcharts();
    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }
}, 2000);
```

});

And this is the layout of the custom gauge:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably more correct to create a proper extension to Highcharts, but it's possible if you add wide borders to the gauge elements and tweak the SVG like this:

```
var svg;
svg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
if (svg.length > 0) {
    var path = svg[0].getElementsByTagName('path');
    if (path.length > 1) {
        // First path is gauge background
        path[0].setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linejoin', 'round');
        // Second path is gauge value
        path[1].setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke-linejoin', 'round');
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Penstrife/1s8sfqtn/

Answer (score 0):

There is a `borderRadius` option in the API which exactly does what you want. Unfortunately this option is only for columns, tooltips, legends but not for `solidgauge`. Here's the nearest thing I could get: http://jsfiddle.net/ao9fv2yh/1/