# Highchart gauge with marker for setting threshold value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image]

I want to get a gauge like this with the black marker for setting threshold value and inner "blue" data as load.

I have used Highcharts (of which I don't have much knowledge) in my code to obtain the required gauge as close as possible, however what I am getting is something like below which is just load without "marker":

[image]

with the code as below:

```
var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '80%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.6, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('container-speed', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Load',
        data: [{
            radius: '100%',
            innerRadius: '80%',
            y: Number($scope.user.threshold)
        }],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ('black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">%</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' %'
        }
    }]

}));
```

Any idea about how can I get the first gauge? Also it should be able to tell when the load crosses the threshold value.

**EDIT (Solved):**

```
yAxis: {
     plotBands: [{
        from: 60,
        to: 61,
        color: 'black',
        thickness: '45%',
        outerRadius: '105%',
        zIndex: 5
    }],  .... }
```

Added this to my code which made it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using plot bands:

```
yAxis: {
  plotBands: {
    from: 70,
    to: 71,
    color: '#DF5353',
    thickness: '40%'
  },
...
}
```

Where thickness is the length of the radius on your marker (easier to understand by looking at the graph).

There is a lot of configuration options here, it should be possible to figure out by looking at the API.

**Working example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6rL9u37d/2/

**API on yAxis.plotBands**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.plotBands

Comment: Thanks, @ewolden its working fine in jsfiddle, but when I am trying to add plotBands its giving error as "TypeError: firstAxis.options.plotBands.unshift is not a function". So I added the 3 js files and deleted my old version highchart.js file but now I am getting error as "Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined" and "Error: Highcharts error #17"

Comment: If you include the input-data and edit your question I might be able to help you. But without that I don't really know what is causing the issues.

Comment: `plotBands: [{
           from: 60,
            to: 61,
            color: 'black',
            thickness: '45%',
            outerRadius: '105%',
            zIndex: 5
        }],`
@ewolden I guess there were some version issues. Adding "[]" made the trick.

Comment: Just 1 more thing about the startAngle, endAngle. I tried for -120 and 120 degreed but the inner data won't support it. Also  how to get those round edges?

Comment: These are really seperate questions, but anyway... For rounded edges and start/end angle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141324/rounded-edges-gauge-with-highcharts-js. That example has both working.